# ArCore: Get Pose for object oriented normally to plane but, rotated in direction of camera

Tags: arcore, hittest, sceneform, plane

I am writing an application using ArCore. I am getting an object's pose as a Hitresult, therefore the object is placed correctly in the plane, but not correctly orientated/rotated towards the smartphone. For a more complete problem description:
The object is a 2d rectangle and is intended to stay inside the plane (= same normal vectors). The rectangle also needs to "point" to the camera (= nearest border needs to be aligned with the smartphone screen).

```
currentObstaclePose = hit.getHitPose().extractTranslation().compose(frame.getCamera().getPose().extractRotation())
```

Using this approach I do not get matching normal vectors for object and plane.

I have no idea how to construct the objects quaternions in a manner to achieve my goal. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you trying to always keep the plane facing you as you walk around? If so, then wouldn't it be easier to just overlay the screen with a 2D plane? Otherwise, its only a matter of centering your object correctly when its anchored and just have one normal pointing up, since their shaders want to do all the lighting anyway...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. No, the plane should just initially be certainly oriented to the camera, but then should stick to the plane. Yes, but how can I achieve the objects normal to be pointing upwards, and also the object to be rotated around the normal correctly with regard to camera?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are trying to do, but I am porting something similar right now that's a mix of 2D and 3D. Perhaps I could help more if you put some screencaps out there of what you're trying to do. In regards to normals, I use the bare minimum of one just for the .obj format, since the shaders are mostly ambient lighting...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to set the 'look direction' of the renderable.

Assuming you are using Scenefrom, which I see is tagged, you can use a TransformableNode and the method setLookDirection.

The example below will set the direction of the renderable, depending on the value you set for lookDirection:

```js
            var newAnchorNode:AnchorNode = AnchorNode(newAnchor)
            var transNode = TransformableNode(arFragment.transformationSystem)
            transNode.setLookDirection(Vector3(0f, xPoint.toFloat(), yPoint.toFloat()), lookDirectionValue) 
            transNode.renderable = yourRenderable
            transNode.setParent(newAnchorNode)
            newAnchorNode.setParent(arFragment.arSceneView.scene)
            setAnchorNodes.add(newAnchorNode)
```